# How to assign a mapped column to a variable in update editor?

Tags: ssis

I need to assign a value that comes from column mapping to a variable that I've just declared, but the package throws a syntax error.

I've tried setting the variables with string values and it works, which means that the error is in the assign of the variable.

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(7);
DECLARE @Surname varchar(7);
SET @Name = ?;
SET @Surname = ?;

UPDATE Person
SET Name = @Name,
Surname = @Surname
WHERE Id = 3000
```

I expect to set the values that comes from the column mapping to the variables @Name and @Surname.

Comment: By "update editor" do you mean the OLE DB Command component or something different?

Comment: Yes, the UPDATE component

Comment: How are you executing that in the SSIS package, via an execute sql task? How is that task configured, how is the Parameter Mapping setup?

Comment: I can't execute it because it marks an error. What do you mean by he configuration of the task? The parameter mapping is with Name with Param_0 and Surname with Param_1.

Comment: I have this error: Error at Data Flow Task [Update - Person [760]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error".


Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "Update - Person" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

Comment: help us help you, we need more details.  Please update your question.  Based the error seems like you're in a data flow task and trying to do an update there. Without knowing the specifics on how you're tempting to set that up, we can't help you.  Are you trying to do that in a source or destination component in the data flow? or via some other component in the data flow? maybe add some screenshots of your data flow along how you have configured the one giving the error.